# .htaccess rewriterule redirect to a page in a subfolder as long as the real page nonexistant

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

FTR, this is most definitely a programmer shortcoming. The problem is that I've got a short url rewriterule on that works fine. I can do www.mysite.com/matt and it'll hit my php page that queries for a result. But what I NEED is to do mysite.com/music/matt

When I use the same rule for a subfolder as I did on the root dir, it throws a 500 error, AND tries to redirect my mysite.com/music/index.php  both of which are a big problem.

Here's what I have that works fine on root (i.e. mysite.com/matt redirects as expected):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /music/artist_page.php?n=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I try the following, I get an internal 500 error and it appears to eat any existing files.

```
RewriteRule ^music/(.*)$ /music/artist_page.php?n=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your substitution destination `music/artist_page.php` is also matched by `^music/(.*)$` and thus you’re getting a recursion. The first condition in your first rule avoids that for that rule as it excludes any request that can be mapped to an existing file.

Comment: Aah! that makes sense! I'm still pretty terrible at htaccess... Hmm, so how do I get around that?

Comment: @Cyprus106: Either use the same condition as well or this condition: `RewriteCond $1 != artist_page.php`. This will just exclude the destination you are redirecting to.